# Getting xml attribute pair of Oracle CLOB with xml structure

Tags: xml, oracle, xmltable

I have the a xml with the following structure:

```
<xml>
    <ele1>
        <ele2>
            <Attribute Key="x1" Value="V1" />
            <Attribute Key="x2" Value="V2" />
            <Attribute Key="x3" Value="V3" />
            <Attribute Key="x4" Value="V4" />
            <Attribute Key="x5" Value="V5" />
        </ele2>
    </ele1>
</xml>
```

For each Key=x1 and Key=x3 I want to get the Values.

The target table/select should have theo following columns:
ele2 | x1 | x2

Actual I have the following code:

```
SELECT Description.*, Other.*
FROM   (select XMLTYPE.createXML(XMLCODE) as XMLCODE from Table) myxml,
       XMLTABLE('/ele1/ele2/Attribute[@Key="x1"]'
         PASSING myxml.XMLCODE
         COLUMNS 
           "Description"    VARCHAR2(255)  PATH '@Value'
         ) Description,
        XMLTABLE('/ele1/ele2/Attribute[@Key="x2"]'
         PASSING myxml.XMLCODE
         COLUMNS 
           "Other"    VARCHAR2(255)  PATH '@Value'
         ) Other;
```

Problem is that the XMLTables are not joined and I get a cartesian product. Any Ideas or is there an easier way?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't demonstrate whatever issue you're having. If the XPath has `/xml` added to the start so it finds anything, it only gets one row back. Even adding a second row of sample data still only gets two results - not four, as you seem to be implying. Can you edit your question to show more representative data, the output you currently get for that, and the output you want? I can guess what you might really have, but I shouldn't need to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need multiple XMLTable calls here; you can extract multiple values from the same node with one, by providing more than one column in the `columns` clause (which is plural - a bit of a clue).

```
select x.*
from myTable t
cross join XMLTable('/xml/ele1/ele2'
  passing xmltype(t.xmlcode)
  columns description varchar2(255) path 'Attribute[@Key="x1"]/@Value',
    other varchar2(255) path 'Attribute[@Key="x2"]/@Value'
) x;
```

Both attribute values are coming from the same `ele2` node.

Comment: Great, thank you! Thats the syntax I was looking for

Comment: Maybe you know a way to exclude null values? Means a where clause x1 Value is not null and x2 value is not null

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. You can filter it from within the XQuery I suppose, but could also just stick a `where` clause on the end to filter the resulsts: `where x.description is not null and x.other is not null`.